# Map function not reflecting props change

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a calendar to display events by date and time (30 mins intervals).

I've reproduced the code in a simplified way below (please check what I'm logging to the console to understand the strange behavior).

```
 Parent {
    this.state = {
        events: [...]
    }

     handleNewEvent() {
        this.setState({events: newArray})
     }

     render() {
        console.log("Parent: " + this.state.events.length);
        <Calendar events={this.state.events} />
        <AnotherComponent handleNewEvent={this.handleNewEvent}
     }
}

Calendar {

    const times =  ['08:00','08:30','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30'];

    render() {
        console.log("Calendar: " + this.props.events.length);

        var items = times.map((time) => {
            console.log("Items.map: " + this.props.events.length);
            return <CalendarRow key={time} time={time} events={this.props.events} />
        })
    }
}

CalendarRow {
    render() {
         console.log("CalendarRow: " + this.props.events.length);
         // Table row where I filter and display events
    }
}
```

When I push a new event to the events array, the `Calendar` and `CalendarRow` receive the new props, however, `CalendarRow` is rendered only once (with the "08:00" value).
This is what appears in the console:

```
// Before updating the state
Parent: 3
Calendar: 3
Items.map: 3 (26 times)
CalendarRow: 3 (26 times)

// After updating the state
Parent: 4
Calendar: 4
Items.map: 4 (26 times)
CalendarRow: 4 (1 time)
```

I don't understand why the map function stops on the first item and all the other items stay the same. I've tried changing the `key`with no success

Comment: You have `return` statements in your `render` methods right?

Comment: Right, I omitted the rest of the code for simplicity

Comment: Do you have any lifecycle hooks on the `Calendar` component? Or is your Calendar component a Pure component?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi No, just the render method and the map function inside it.

Comment: Hmm, not sure where the problem could be, is it possible for you to create a working snippet in JSFiddle or Stackblitz?